# Rails - Text's double spaces to single space

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

```
text_from_db = "I love  Ruby"
```

When I display this in the view, it shows as "I love Ruby". There should be two spaces after the word 'love'. I've tried simple_format but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are there 2 spaces when you look at the HTML source of the page?

Comment: Yes the source has two spaces.

Comment: This is an HTML/CSS question, not a Ruby question. All HTML whitespace is collapsed to a single space when presented on screen, unless you specify otherwise. The fact that Ruby is outputting two spaces into the source is a good indication that the Ruby isn't the problem :)

Comment: You da man Gareth! <pre> tags worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is an HTML question, the clue is that you *do* see two spaces in the HTML source. All you need to do is make sure that the

```
white-space: pre;
```

CSS property is applied to your text, for example by using the `<pre>` elemeent